# Variable Matplotlib Histogram Bin Width

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am making a figure with 3 subplots and some of the histogram bins are appearing to be different sizes, despite them all being equal width. My goal is to create a histogram with equal width bars.

I am plotting data from three different data frames `df1,df2,df3` and each gets its own axis.  The first two data frames (`df1,df2`) have 12 values, while the third (`df3`) has 21 values.  A minimal working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick': {0: -0.10257269427388138,1: -0.39092250646203491,2:-0.23459561055233191,3: 0.68753181981137268,4: -0.86443211703287937,5: -0.46963178960649432,6: 0.14070311160589327,7: 0.1885440568340489,8: 0.64210565529921859,9: -0.81346415594104837,10: 0.68175896505459788,11: 0.33673654536030828}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick':{0: -0.38775619399296002,1: -0.32367407025583783,2: -0.56055783338428344,3: 0.23824247437746471,4: -0.64925233000340721,5: -0.44120245730257612,6: 0.027222094241818928,7: -0.091069018106476163,8: 0.0066066466889458386,9: -0.60477189852646174,10: 0.12878952794346843,11: -0.0077463979905486591}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick':{0: 0.28518349971907864,1: -0.06724843620619711,2: 0.32596222283195153,3: 0.44928934543390797,4: 0.20911991461399143,5: -0.036989014816141919,6: -0.21517978702947216, 7: -0.028429332303918198,8: 0.037553921139760305,9: 0.98813506475654656,10: 0.51938760439670373,11: 0.11348101736407434,12: 0.79676269452200232,13: 0.27961307494052506,14: -0.55282685608381399,15: 0.63549900861027275,16: -0.20869225741458663,17: 0.55296943711112945,18: 0.34448294335085694,19: 0.18268186220418725,20: 0.36422880308671302}})

fig, (ax,ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,1,21)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df1.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
df1.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax, bins=division,color='green',label='Thing',hatch='//')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 1.5, 0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
ax.set_title('A. 1990-2016')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Sites')
ax.legend(fontsize='x-small',loc=2)

#Deficit
bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,0.6,16)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df2.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
df2.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax1, bins=division,color='green',hatch='//')
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 0.75, 0.5))
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
ax1.set_title('B. 1990-2003')
ax1.set_xlabel('X axis label')

#Enrich
bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,0.6,16)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df3.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
df3.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax2, bins=division,color='green',hatch='//')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 1.5, 0.5))
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
ax2.set_title('C. 2003-2016')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: output figure]

In the above plot, the third subplot `ax2` has a histogram bar that appears to have a bin width of 0.2.

Could the length of the third data frame be causing this issue?

Doesn't the variable `division` dictate the bin width?

Comment: I think that the bins are all fine, it's just that one of the vertical line doesn't show up. I have run your code on python3, matplotlib 2.0.2 with Qt5Agg backend and I don't see at all the vertical lines separating the bins. If I save the figure as ``png`` I get something very similar to the Qt5Agg backend. If I save as PDF, some of the bins don't even show the hatching. I don't know if it's a bug in matplotlib or in whatever displays the figures.

Comment: @FrancescoMontesano thanks for testing

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont know why, but somehow when I was adjusting the x ticks (i.e. `ax2.xaxis.set_ticks`) it altered the appearance of the histogram bars.  So the working solution is:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#Data
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick': {0: -0.10257269427388138,1: -0.39092250646203491,2:-0.23459561055233191,3: 0.68753181981137268,4: -0.86443211703287937,5: -0.46963178960649432,6: 0.14070311160589327,7: 0.1885440568340489,8: 0.64210565529921859,9: -0.81346415594104837,10: 0.68175896505459788,11: 0.33673654536030828}})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick':{0: -0.38775619399296002,1: -0.32367407025583783,2: -0.56055783338428344,3: 0.23824247437746471,4: -0.64925233000340721,5: -0.44120245730257612,6: 0.027222094241818928,7: -0.091069018106476163,8: 0.0066066466889458386,9: -0.60477189852646174,10: 0.12878952794346843,11: -0.0077463979905486591}})
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Delta_Thick':{0: 0.28518349971907864,1: -0.06724843620619711,2: 0.32596222283195153,3: 0.44928934543390797,4: 0.20911991461399143,5: -0.036989014816141919,6: -0.21517978702947216, 7: -0.028429332303918198,8: 0.037553921139760305,9: 0.98813506475654656,10: 0.51938760439670373,11: 0.11348101736407434,12: 0.79676269452200232,13: 0.27961307494052506,14: -0.55282685608381399,15: 0.63549900861027275,16: -0.20869225741458663,17: 0.55296943711112945,18: 0.34448294335085694,19: 0.18268186220418725,20: 0.36422880308671302}})

fig, (ax,ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=3)

bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,1,21)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df1.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
df1.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax, bins=division,color='green',hatch='//')
ax.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 1.5, 0.5))
ax.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
ax.set_title('A. 1990-2016')
ax.set_ylabel('Number of Sites')
ax.legend(fontsize='x-small',loc=2)

#Deficit
bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,1,21)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df2.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
#ax1.hist(df2.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=counts.size)
df2.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax1, bins=division,color='green',hatch='//')
ax1.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 1.5, 0.5))
ax1.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 5, 1))
ax1.set_title('B. 1990-2003')
ax1.set_xlabel('X axis label')

#Enrich

bins=[round(x,1)for x in np.linspace(-1,1,21)]
counts, division = np.histogram(df3.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'],bins=bins)
df3.loc[:,'Delta_Thick'].hist(ax=ax2, bins=division,color='green',hatch='//')
ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 2, 0.5))
ax2.yaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(0, 10, 1))
ax2.set_title('C. 2003-2016')


plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Notice I changed `ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 1.5, 0.5))` to `ax2.xaxis.set_ticks(np.arange(-1, 2, 0.5))`.

[image]

Comment: I think that part of the problem is that sometimes the border of one bar gets behind the nearby one. You can also try to increase the width of the border lines: I don't know if this works, but it's worth a try.